# File Reading Nesting For Loops won't Loop Multiple Times

Tags: python, for-loop

I know the outer for loop is supposed to run once and the inner one runs fully, but once the inner for loop finishes, the outer for loop never continues again with the second line in the file. What's wrong here?

```
import csv
import pprint
import sys


team = []

with open("sample_runner_data.csv", "r") as sample_csv:
    sample_csv = csv.DictReader(sample_csv)
    for lines in sample_csv:
        theLine = lines["team"]
        for line in sample_csv:
            if(theLine == line["team"]):
                print(line["team"])
                team.append(line["time"])
'''
The output of the above print(line["team]) statement is as follows. Abra is simply the team 
name and there are 7 teams named Abra.

Abra
Abra
Abra
Abra
Abra
Abra
Abra
'''
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the csv and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same underlying `sample_csv` file, which means once you  iterator through once it is exhausted and all subsequent iterators will end. Read in the data then perform the loops:

```
with open("sample_runner_data.csv", "r") as sample_csv:
    sample_csv = csv.DictReader(sample_csv)
    data = list(sample_csv)

for lines in data:
    theLine = lines["team"]
    for line in data:
        if(theLine == line["team"]):
            print(line["team"])
            team.append(line["time"])
```

However, this is perhaps not what you are looking for if you are just looking for gather all the times for each team, e.g.:

```
data = {}
with open("sample_runner_data.csv", "r") as sample_csv:
    sample_csv = csv.DictReader(sample_csv)
    for line in sample_csv:
        data.setdefault(line['team'], []).append(line['time'])
```

Now `data` will contain `team` as key with all the `time`s as values.